# Using Scanner to read file and store in ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop, java.util.scanner

My Code so far. (Keep in mind this is my first programming class and While loops are still hard and new to me.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.Group;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class InsultGenerator extends Application
{
ArrayList<String> adjectives1;
ArrayList<String> adjectives2; 
ArrayList<String> nouns;

public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File file = new File("insultData.txt");
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);

    while (inFile.hasNext())
    {

    }


}
}
```

So I have a project for my school that requires me to take a text file with 3 columns of text. I have to read the text file and store each column in 3 different ArrayLists. Here is the exact statement that described what is wanted.

Use a Scanner object to read the input file. Remember to add a throws FileNotFoundException clause to the start method header.

At the class level (so they can be used in other methods), declare and create three ArrayList objects called adjectives1, adjectives2, and nouns. All three lists should hold String objects.

When reading the input file, use a while loop to check to see if the input file still has data to read:

```
while (inFile.hasNext())
{
   // read and store data
}
```

Each iteration of the while loop should read one line of data. Store the first adjective on the line in the adjectives1 list, the second in the adjectives2 list, and the noun in the nouns list. Use the next method of the Scanner to read each word. You may assume that each line will have all three values.

Note that you don't have to know how many lines of input data there will be. An ArrayList doesn't have a fixed capacity and expands and contracts as needed.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a specific question - just posted some code and your assignment.

Comment: Sorry, this was my first time posting and asking anything, but I didn't know if what was needed and if I could explain it correctly so that's why I posted the assignment description. The only thing I was wondering was how to correctly read the text of the file and store it into the separate array lists. I had read multiple other questions and articles but still couldn't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In the while loop, first read the next line of text to a String. Then, split the String into an array. Finally, push each element of the array to each array list.

```
String line = inFilw.nextLine();
String[] words = line.split(" ");
adjectives1.add(words[0]);
adjectives2.add(words[1]);
nouns.add(words[2]);
```